# Энерго(-)механическая

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "энергомеханическая" или "энерго-механическая"?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно применяется слитная форма написания: энергомеханический.

Вот пример: «БЕЛООЗЕРСКИЙ ЭНЕРГОМЕХАНИЧЕСКИЙ ЗАВОД» – одно из ведущих предприятий энергетической системы по производству оборудования и запасных частей для тепловых, электрических, атомных и гидростанций.

Сложное прилагательное образовано способом чистого (бессуффиксального) сложения: энерг/ия + механический (с усечением первой основы и использованием соединительной гласной). Соответственно, оно пишется слитно.

С другой стороны, возможно и дефисное написание, которое встречается значительно реже. В этом случае мы считаем, что сложное прилагательное образовано сложением основ прилагательных энергетический и механический, но основа первого прилагательного также усечена.

Другие примеры парных написаний:

А) лавровишневые капли, хлебобулочные изделия, хромоникелевый сплав.

Б) приемо-сдаточные испытания, мясо-молочные продукты, лирико-эпический характер, англо-русский словарь – сочинительная связь основ, усечение первой основы прилагательного.

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Внесены изменения.